# Tabs reusing the same usercontrol? WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've got a tabcontrol, that has in its datatemplate a usercontrol (simply just a range slider). However, when i switch tabs, it seems to values of the first slider is the same as the second slider given 2 tabs. I want the behaviour to be separate from eachother... i thought that it would be separate and they wouldn't be mimicking eachother, what am i doing wrong?

```
                        <TabControl Grid.Row="2" 
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PrColour}" 
                                Background="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PrColour}"
                                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Plole}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Sams}">
                            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SName}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <views:RangeSliderUserControl x:Name="slider"
                                                   Margin="10" LowerValue="30" UpperValue="70"
                                                   Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Minimum}" Margin="10,1,10,1"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=LowerValue}" Margin="10,1,10,1" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=UpperValue}" Margin="10,1,10,1" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Maximum}" Margin="10,1,10,1" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                        </TabControl>
```

The slider code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Ut.Views.RangeSliderUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ut.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="RangeSlider"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/CsourceDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="1" 
                Margin="5,0,5,0"/>

        <Slider x:Name="LowerSlider"
                Minimum="{Binding ElementName=RangeSlider, Path=Minimum}"
                Maximum="{Binding ElementName=RangeSlider, Path=Maximum}"
                Value="{Binding ElementName=RangeSlider, Path=LowerValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Template="{StaticResource SimpleSlider}"
                Margin="0,0,10,0"
                />

        <Slider x:Name="UpperSlider"
                Minimum="{Binding ElementName=RangeSlider, Path=Minimum}"
                Maximum="{Binding ElementName=RangeSlider, Path=Maximum}"
                Value="{Binding ElementName=RangeSlider, Path=UpperValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Template="{StaticResource SimpleSlider}"
                Margin="10,0,0,0"
                />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Ut.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for RangeSliderUserControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class RangeSliderUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public RangeSliderUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += Slider_Loaded;
        }

        void Slider_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LowerSlider.ValueChanged += LowerSlider_ValueChanged;
            UpperSlider.ValueChanged += UpperSlider_ValueChanged;
        }

        private void LowerSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            UpperSlider.Value = Math.Max(UpperSlider.Value, LowerSlider.Value);
        }

        private void UpperSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            LowerSlider.Value = Math.Min(UpperSlider.Value, LowerSlider.Value);
        }

        public double Minimum
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(MinimumProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSliderUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));

        public double LowerValue
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(LowerValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LowerValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LowerValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LowerValue", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSliderUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));

        public double UpperValue
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(UpperValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UpperValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty UpperValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("UpperValue", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSliderUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));

        public double Maximum
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSliderUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(1d));

    }
}
```

I tried to use properties in the Sams like so:

```
                                            <views:RangeSliderUserControl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="slider" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                              LowerValue="{Binding LowerValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                                              UpperValue="{Binding UpperValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                                              Minimum="{Binding MinimumXValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                                              Maximum="{Binding MaximumXValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I don't get a binding error, but now my thumbs don't move and i don't know what's wrong...

Comment: You should bind to properties of the objects in the `Sams` source collection rather than binding to properties of the control.

Comment: @mm8 Sams would have to have those 4 variables that are part of the slider to be properties wouldn't it. Since they all emcompass the same thing i.e. a slider, would it be possible to create a model that encompass those 4 properties and have that as part of the model that is made up of Sams?

Comment: I.e. if Sams was an observable collection of A, then A which is a model, could encompass another model in it (B for example) and B would have those 4 properties.